# Bootstrap Scrolling Nav: fix sections height and active menu highlight

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

1. when you click the `<a>` link in the navigation the anchor point looks like wrong, because you can't see the section headline. `<h2>` in my case.
2. Is possible to highlight the `<a>` link? Something like a border or smething like this...

This is the HTML code:

```
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ark">Architektur</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#">Wohnen</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ausstattung">Ausstattung</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#lage">Lage</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#">Galerie</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<!-- === END NAV === -->
```

EDIT:

[Nav Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2hg8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. The fixed navbar overlaps your heading, that is the reason you say it's not displayed correctly - to fix this you can add some additional 50px or so when you calculate the top position of the anchor point
2. You need to create a class named "active" or "selected" which will contain desired styles like:
   `selected{
       background-color: silver;
       color: #fff;
   }`

```js
var links = $(".page-scroll"); 
links.on('click',function(){ 
  links.removeClass("selected"); 
  $(this).addClass("selected"); 
});
```

```css
li{

  list-style-type: none;
}
.page-scroll{
  float:left;
  padding:15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
}

.selected{
  background-color: silver;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ark">Architektur</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll selected" href="#">Wohnen</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#ausstattung">Ausstattung</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#lage">Lage</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#">Galerie</a></li>
        <li><a class="page-scroll" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>  
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Then you need to add this class when the anchor from navbar is clicked

Comment: How can i "add this class when the anchor from navbar is clicked"?

Comment: var links = $(".page-scroll");

links.on('click',function(){
   links.removeClass("selected");
   $(this).addClass("selected");
});

Comment: If i add that class and this script the navigation is all grey. I edited the first post so you can see what i mean.

Comment: You must've been doing sth wrong. It cannot happen that. Check the snippet above.

Another problem was <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
You've put page-scroll class on li not on a

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what do you mean in your first problem but with highlighting the `<a></a>` here is the code:

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
li{
  padding: 8px;
}

a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a:hover, a:focus{
  color: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}

.active{
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  border-bottom: 5px solid red;
}
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a').removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
    });
  });
```

Working fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ko4L5fgu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For problem number 1, solution is - add this to your CSS file (3 first lines can be taken out as they are just my comments):

```
/* FIXES problem:
Navbar hides initial content when jumping to in-page anchor #1768
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/1768 */

*[id]:before { 
    display: block; 
    content: " "; 
    margin-top: -75px; 
    height: 75px; 
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```